# How to set context.xml in tomcat run configuration in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat7

I'm trying to deploy a war file for local development and I want to modify tomcat's context.xml to provide datasource via jndi. This works when using `tomcat7-maven-plugin`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <contextFile>../../tomcat-test-context.xml</contextFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is, that tomcat7-maven-plugin doesn't work with overlays which I use in the project, so I have to use another approach. I can deploy the war artifact in intellij idea, but I don't see any option to specify the contextFile like in the tomcat7-maven-plugin. Is there some option to do similar thing in intellij idea tomcat configuration?

Of course I can modify the `context.xml` under the catalina home, but I'd like to have it configured per project and don't want to have many tomcats.

The application is deployed on weblogic in production and I use tomcat only locally for testing.